# Trouble with javascript function to generate exact change

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm working on a challenge from an online coding community.
The object is to write a function that generate exact change
from highest to lowestusing the denominations shown in the
CID array (cash in drawer). The function takes three
arguments, price, cash, cid. Cid is cash in drawer.

I'm trying to compare the cash amounts of the
denominations in cid against the cash amounts of
an exact change computation.

For example, if change = 96, then exact change from highest to 
lowest would be

```
['twenty', 80], ['ten', 1], ['five', 1],
['one', 1]
```

. However, if CID shows ['twenty', 60], ['ten', 20], ["five, 55] then
the code must compute exact change using the amount in cid.
In this case, the result would be,

```
['twenty', 60], ['ten', 20],
['five', 15], ['one', 1]
```

in my code below, the display() function includes a conditional statement
intended to make the comparison and switch in the CID value
if necessary. However, this is causing a duplicate value for
["TWENTY"] to appear. My questions ar what is causing this and
how do I fix it.

The input for the function produces the incorrect result of:

```
 [ [ 'TWENTY', 60 ],
  [ 'TWENTY', 20 ],
  [ 'TEN', 10 ],
  [ 'FIVE', 5 ],
  [ 'ONE', 1 ],
  [ 'QUARTER', 0.5 ],
  [ 'DIME', 0.2 ],
  [ 'PENNY', 0.04 ] ]
```

I have included the code below, but I have a model set up]
at http://repl.it/BAku/2.

```
function drawer(price, cash, cid){
    var change = cash - price;
    change = change.toFixed(2);
    change = +change;
    var combine = [];

    var cidMap = [ cid[0], cid[1], cid[2], cid[3], cid[4], cid[5], cid[6], cid[7], cid[8] ];

    var denomMap = [
        100, 'ONE HUNDRED', 20, 'TWENTY', 10, 'TEN', 5, 'FIVE', 1, 'ONE', 0.25, 'QUARTER', 0.1, 'DIME', 0.05, 'NICKEL', 0.01, "PENNY"
    ];

    function total(cid){
        var cashAmts = [];
        cid.forEach(function(v){
            cashAmts.push(v[1]);
        },0);
            var sum = cashAmts.reduce(function(a, b){return a + b;
            }).toFixed(2);
            return +sum;
    }

            if(cash < price){
                return price;
            }
            else if(total(cid) < change){
                return "Insufficient Funds";
            }
            else if(total(cid) === change){
                return "Closed";
            }
            else if(total(cid) > change){
                return display(change, cid);
        }



    function display(change) {
        var temp;
        num = change;
        var num = change;
        var value = '';
        for (var i = 0; change > 0 && i < denomMap.length; i += 2) {
            while (change >= denomMap[i]) {
                change += denomMap[i + 1];
                change = change.replace(/\d+/g, "");
                change = change.replace(/\./g, "");
                value += denomMap[i];
                var div = Math.floor(num/+value) * denomMap[i];

                if(change === cidMap[0][0] && div > cidMap[0][1]){
                    div = cidMap[0][1];
                }
                else if(change === cidMap[1][0] && div > cidMap[1][1]){
                    div = cidMap[1][1];
                }
                 else if(change === cidMap[2][0] && div > cidMap[2][1]){
                    div = cidMap[2][1];
                }
                 else if(change === cidMap[3][0] && div > cidMap[3][1]){
                    div = cidMap[3][1];
                }
                 else if(change === cidMap[4][0] && div > cidMap[4][1]){
                    div = cidMap[4][1];
                }
                 else if(change === cidMap[5][0] && div > cidMap[5][1]){
                    div = cidMap[5][1];
                }
                 else if(change === cidMap[6][0] && div > cidMap[6][1]){
                    div = cidMap[6][1];
                }
                 else if(change === cidMap[7][0] && div > cidMap[7][1]){
                    div = cidMap[7][1];
                }
                else if(change === cidMap[8][0] && div > cidMap[8][1]){
                    div = cidMap[8][1];
                }

                temp = [change, div];
                combine.push(temp);
                num = (num - div).toFixed(2);
                num = +num;
                display(num);
            }
        }

        return combine;
    }  

}

drawer(3.26, 100.00, [['PENNY', 1.01], ['NICKEL', 2.05], ['DIME', 3.10], ['QUARTER', 4.25], ['ONE', 90.00], ['FIVE', 55.00], ['TEN', 20.00], ['TWENTY', 60.00], ['ONE HUNDRED', 100.00]]);
```

Comment: While the `reduce` call is lacking a second argument (start value for the accumulator), the `forEach` has a second argument 0 and doesn't need one.

Comment: Should your first example be `['twenty', 80], ['ten', 10], ['five', 5],
['one', 1]`? I.e. do you want to show the value of each denomination or the number of each?

Comment: @RobG - Thank you for your comment. The result should return the dollar value amount of the denomination. In the first example, exact change from highest to lowest is ['twenty', 80], ['ten', 10], ['five', 5], ['one', 1]. However the cash drawer only has ['twenty', 50] and ['ten', 20]. That means the solution can only use those amounts when generating the exact change.

Comment: I offer an alternative [test driven functional-programming refactoring](http://jsbin.com/lejaka/edit?js,console) of your code to remove the recursion and nested looping. Hopefully this is easier to reason about.

Comment: Thank you for the refactored solution. I appreciate your modelling professional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is causing this?

You are taking all of the three `'TWENTY'` notes out of the drawer but not updating the drawer to reflect that there are now no `'TWENTY'` notes left. So on the next loop iteration, the drawer incorrectly thinks that you still have another `'TWENTY'` note to give.

> How do I fix it?

Update the cash in the drawer after making a withdrawal and include a check for remaining cash. Here is one way to do it with minimal modifications to your original code to help give you some insight.

Take note of the `changeAvailable` function and where it is called. Also take note of the updates to the drawer (e.g for the three `TWENTY` notes: `cidMap[7][1] = 0;`).

http://jsbin.com/vapobu/edit?js,console

```
(function () {

  "use strict";

function drawer(price, cash, cid){
    var change = cash - price;
    change = change.toFixed(2);
    change = +change;
    var combine = [];

    var cidMap = [ cid[0], cid[1], cid[2], cid[3], cid[4], cid[5], cid[6], cid[7], cid[8] ];

    var denomMap = [
        100, 'ONE HUNDRED', 20, 'TWENTY', 10, 'TEN', 5, 'FIVE', 1, 'ONE', 0.25, 'QUARTER', 0.1, 'DIME', 0.05, 'NICKEL', 0.01, "PENNY"
    ];

    function display(change) {
        var temp;
        //num = change;//use global variables sparingly, preferably within a namespace, suspect type-o
        var num = change;
        var value = '',
            changeAvailable = function (nameOfCurrency) {
              var queryCash = cid.filter(function (currentCurrency) {
                return currentCurrency[0] === nameOfCurrency;
              }),
                  cashRemaining = queryCash[0][1];
              return (cashRemaining !== 0);            
            };
        for (var i = 0; change > 0 && i < denomMap.length; i += 2) {
            while (change >= denomMap[i] && changeAvailable(denomMap[i + 1])) {
                change += denomMap[i + 1];
                change = change.replace(/\d+/g, "");
                change = change.replace(/\./g, "");
                value += denomMap[i];
                var div;
                   div = Math.floor(num/+value) * denomMap[i];

                if(change === cidMap[0][0] && div > cidMap[0][1]){
                    div = cidMap[0][1];
                    cidMap[0][1] = 0;
                }
                else if(change === cidMap[1][0] && div > cidMap[1][1]){
                    div = cidMap[1][1];
                    cidMap[1][1] = 0;
                }
                 else if(change === cidMap[2][0] && div > cidMap[2][1]){
                    div = cidMap[2][1];
                    cidMap[2][1] = 0;
                }
                 else if(change === cidMap[3][0] && div > cidMap[3][1]){
                    div = cidMap[3][1];
                    cidMap[3][1] = 0;
                }
                 else if(change === cidMap[4][0] && div > cidMap[4][1]){
                    div = cidMap[4][1];
                    cidMap[4][1] = 0;
                }
                 else if(change === cidMap[5][0] && div > cidMap[5][1]){
                    div = cidMap[5][1];
                    cidMap[5][1] = 0;
                }
                 else if(change === cidMap[6][0] && div > cidMap[6][1]){
                    div = cidMap[6][1];
                    cidMap[6][1] = 0;
                }
                 else if(change === cidMap[7][0] && div > cidMap[7][1]){
                    div = cidMap[7][1];
                    cidMap[7][1] = 0;
                    //temp = [change, div];//duplicated code
                }
                else if(change === cidMap[8][0] && div > cidMap[8][1]){
                    div = cidMap[8][1];
                    cidMap[8][1] = 0;
                }

                temp = [change, div];
                combine.push(temp);
                num = (num - div).toFixed(2);
                num = +num;
                display(num);
            }
        }

        return combine;
    }

      function total(cid){
        var cashAmts = [];
        cid.forEach(function(v){
            cashAmts.push(v[1]);
        },0);
            var sum = cashAmts.reduce(function(a, b){return a + b;
            }).toFixed(2);
            return +sum;
    }

            if(cash < price){
                return price;
            }
            else if(total(cid) < change){
                return "Insufficient Funds";
            }
            else if(total(cid) === change){
                return "Closed";
            }
            else if(total(cid) > change){
                return display(change, cid);
        }
}

console.log(drawer(3.26, 100.00, [['PENNY', 1.01], ['NICKEL', 2.05], ['DIME', 3.10], ['QUARTER', 4.25], ['ONE', 90.00], ['FIVE', 55.00], ['TEN', 20.00], ['TWENTY', 60.00], ['ONE HUNDRED', 100.00]]));

}());
```

Comment: Thank you very much! After I posted, I later realized that the problem was precisely the reason you stated. However, I couldn't come up with a solution. Your changeAvailable() function and the way it interacts with the while-loop is really sweet!

Comment: Glad I could help. It was an interesting challenge.

Comment: The IFFE is nice touch, too.